# What's an example of a linear function $f: \mathbb Q^3 \to \mathbb Q^3$ such that there are no proper invariant subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Is there a linear automorphism $f$ on $\mathbb Q^3$ such that the only $f$-invariant subspaces of $\mathbb Q^3$ are $0$ and $\mathbb Q^3$, and, if so, then what is an example?

Comment: Try $f(a,b,c)=(2c,a,b)$?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** [It suffices to find a linear transformation $\Bbb Q^3 \to \Bbb Q^3$ whose characteristic polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3144937/irreducible-characteristic-polynomial-and-invariant-subspaces) On the other hand, we can build a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) with prescribed characteristic polynomial $p(t) = t^3 + a_2 t^2 + a_1 t + a_0$, namely,
$$C_p :=
\pmatrix{
0 & 0 & -a_0 \\
1 & 0 & -a_1 \\
0 & 1 & -a_2
} .
$$

> So, to find a linear transformation $\Bbb Q^3 \to \Bbb Q^3$ we can pick any (monic) cubic polynomial $t^3 + a_2 t^2 + a_1 t + a_0$ irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ and interpret its companion matrix $C_p$ as a linear transformation $T_p : \Bbb Q^3 \to \Bbb Q^3$ by fixing any basis of $\Bbb Q^3$; taking the standard basis defines the transformation $$T_p (x, y, z) = (y, z, -(a_0 x + a_1 y + a_2 z)) .$$ Applying the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to the polynomial $p$ with $a_0 = -2, a_1 = a_2 = 0$ quickly shows that it is irreducible, giving a concrete example that coincides with Mindlack's example in the comments up to reordering of components.